# Laravel application keeps loading and nothing comes up

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, preloading

I have a problem with my Laravel application. When I execute the command:
`php artisan serve` it returns me the message:

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Tue May 31 16:37:37 2022] PHP 8.1.6 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

and when I try to access the link `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, the website keeps loading on and nothing comes up.

I've change my php version and I've update my composer and still doesn't work, also I've tried to change the application port and also doesn't work.

Comment: Does `http://localhost:8000/` work instead? (Both `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000` work for me, but that might not be the case for everyone). Beyond that, you might need to add more information; is this a fresh Laravel project? What code is being executed (i.e. what route, controller and view, etc. are associated with the `/` route)

Comment: @TimLewis ```http://localhost:8000/``` doesn't work either. The project was installed a few months ago and after I've change my php version this happen. I think this might be the reason but I've change everything with the newest version. Also I've tried to reinstall the composer and still doesn't fix the problem.

And I don't think is a problem from the code because I've tried to install a new Laravel project and still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, interesting; I can't say I've run into that issue before, and I've migrated projects from different versions of both Laravel and PHP. What's your development OS? Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: I've also got this issue before but it fixed by changing port for the application but doesn't work in this situation.
My Operating system is Windows.